# Extracting frames from Raw video

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ffmpeg, v4l2

I set the configuration as :

```
v4l2-ctl -v pixelformat=pRCC,width=4056,height=3040
v4l2-ctl -p 10
```

then get the frames with :

```
v4l2-ctl --stream-mmap=3 --stream-count=100 --stream-to=test.avi
```

that ends successfully. Now I am stuck at trying to extract frames from this video file and convert them to RGB for viewing.

I have two modes for camera operation, first one is to directly connecting the it to the address bus than listing formats results as :

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext

ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
Type: Video Capture

[0]: 'pRCC' (12-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB Packed)
    Size: Discrete 4056x3040
    Size: Discrete 2028x1520
    Size: Discrete 2028x1080
[1]: 'RG12' (12-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB)
    Size: Discrete 4056x3040
    Size: Discrete 2028x1520
    Size: Discrete 2028x1080
[2]: 'pRAA' (10-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB Packed)
    Size: Discrete 1012x760
[3]: 'RG10' (10-bit Bayer RGRG/GBGB)
    Size: Discrete 1012x760
```

If I connect over the operating system then the result is :

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
Type: Video Capture

[0]: 'YU12' (Planar YUV 4:2:0)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[2]: 'RGB3' (24-bit RGB 8-8-8)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[3]: 'JPEG' (JFIF JPEG, compressed)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[4]: 'H264' (H.264, compressed)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[5]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[6]: 'YVYU' (YVYU 4:2:2)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[7]: 'VYUY' (VYUY 4:2:2)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[8]: 'UYVY' (UYVY 4:2:2)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[9]: 'NV12' (Y/CbCr 4:2:0)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[10]: 'BGR3' (24-bit BGR 8-8-8)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[11]: 'YV12' (Planar YVU 4:2:0)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[12]: 'NV21' (Y/CrCb 4:2:0)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
[13]: 'RX24' (32-bit XBGR 8-8-8-8)
    Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 4056x3040 with step 2/2
```

As I mentioned, I am trying to get untouched 12bit data as fast as I can then being able to view the pixel data at Python, preferably (I am also open to other suggestions).

I would be glad if experienced users would provide some solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to RGB"? What format do you want to end up with?

Comment: you MUST NOT call that file ".avi". it is not a proper .avi file. it is just raw bytes. when you've done that, you can progress.

Comment: @SumnerEvans I want it to be png file for example

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I changed the extension, thanks for the pointer but still can not view RGB pixel values or view the data

Comment: What are you actually trying to do please? Why do you set `pRCC` format if you want RGB? What hardware/software environment are you in? What video device?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am trying to read frames from a Sony imx477 sensor to Raspberry Pi 4, I am using v4l2-ctl because it accesses the video device faster. When I read jpeg or png directly from device it is much slower thus I am capturing frames, saving them sequentially to a file as raw. What I can not achieve is to split/extract frames from this "video" file and convert them to commonly processable RGB format. I can work with both C/C++ or Python solutions as well, considering OpenCV

Comment: Could you maybe take `RGGB8` format?

Comment: I would highly recommend using V4L2 *APIs* instead of dumping into a file. or use any other API such as ffmpeg's libav*, or if you must, OpenCV's VideoCapture, which uses ffmpeg or V4L2.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can only get 10bit or 12bit Bayer format, I am trying to convert to any form of 8bit RGB format

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Unfortunately these solutions are rather slow when compared to raw capture that's why I looking for ways to convert Bayer 12bit data. For example I gave 'dcraw' a shot but it provided meaningless outputs for conversion

Comment: Maybe you could click `edit` under your question and include the list of available formats `v4l2-ctl --list-formats` and `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I made the necessary changes

Comment: You say you want to access the frames as quickly as possible. Do you mean you want to read a frame and display it as soon as possible continuously in OpenCV? Or do you mean you want to record a whole bunch of frames to a file and then read that file? Did you think of recording an image of something red and sharing the recorded file via Dropbox or Google Drive, then doing the same for an image of something blue?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It actually doesn't matter if I read frame by frame or capture as whole then split/extract to frames. I don't see the purpose of uploading to public domain if you don't mind

Comment: It's fine if you don't want to, or are unable to. It just means I won't be able to try to help you. Good luck with your project anyway 